# Cropped image smaller than crop (Reactjs + react-image-crop)

Tags: reactjs, react-image-crop

I'm trying to implement `react-image-crop` in my React.JS project. I have a little issue : my cropped image isn't the same dimensions as my crop.. I'm using the following functions on my `<ReactCrop>`  component :

```
handleImageLoaded = (image) => {
    //
  };

  handleOnCropChange = (percentCrop) => {
    this.setState({ crop: percentCrop });
  };

  handleOnCropComplete = (percentCrop) => {
    if (this.imageRef && percentCrop.width && percentCrop.height) {
      const canvasRef = this.imagePreviewCanvasRef.current;
      const { imgSrc } = this.state;

      image64toCanvasRef(canvasRef, imgSrc, percentCrop);
    }
  };
```

And here's my `image64toCanvasRef` function :

```
export function image64toCanvasRef(canvasRef, image64, percentCrop) {
  const canvas = canvasRef; // document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = percentCrop.width;
  canvas.height = percentCrop.height;

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = image64;

  image.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      percentCrop.x,
      percentCrop.y,
      percentCrop.width,
      percentCrop.height,
      0,
      0,
      percentCrop.width,
      percentCrop.height
    );
  };
}
```

Here's what it looks like when i upload an image and crop : [image: image + crop]

So my guess is the issue lies in the `ctx.drawImage()`

Comment: Looks like the preview image is not the actual image size or dims. Inspect it in your browser, see if CSS is styling it in anyway.

Comment: Ah! Yes you're right! But how can i style it so if the user uploads for example a 3000x3000 file it still works ? Right now i've removed the styling on the div that's containing the image, but if the image is larger than the screen then i have the same issue + it fills the entire screen

Comment: First, you have to make sure its proportionately the same, preview vs actual image dimensions. Since you have to scale it down, you have to compensate in your crop how much you had to scale it down in  your preview.

Comment: Unfortunately that is where my help ends, I do not know enough about React to help implementing this. I would think React Crop has tooling to do this for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i've pretty much figured it out!